# How to terminate long running VFS operation

Tags: vfs, apache-commons-vfs

I need to terminate long running SFTP put operations (sometimes the transfer hangs and takes 10-15 minutes to complete).

Is there a way to do this using Apache VFS? The SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder has a setTimeout method, but that only affects the connect operation. What I would need is to be able to terminate a PUT operation if it takes longer than X minutes.